# How can I create a totally dependent SWF from an existing dynamic one?

Tags: apache-flex, static, import, flash, flashmenu

I manage a website that has ModX and for some reason, I just can't get dynamic SWF files to load. This is not normally a problem as I have a Flash menu creator program that makes static SWF files. However, this new one only makes dynamic SWFs (ones that rely on external files and XML). I've tried making a Projector of the file but with the same result: it still needs the external files. After much searching on Google, I have come across Adobe Flex. I have managed to import the main menu SWF file onto the stage using this code:

`<mx:SWFLoader id="loader1" source="menu.swf" scaleContent="false" autoLoad="true" width="183" height="440" alpha="1.0" left="0" top="0"/>`

Also, I have referenced the folder of the source files (XML file, PNGs and other icon SWFs) and the menu shows up wonderfully in Flex itself. However, if I publish it as an SWF I end up with the same problem. It won't play on its own, without the dependent files. Could anyone take me through the code, step by step as to how to make an independent SWF file with a transparent background, please?

I can always provide more details if necessary. Please bear in mind that I'm almost a complete coding newbie. I'm really tearing my hair out here! The menu can be viewed here:
[HTML Version of Flash Menu - CLICK HERE TO VIEW](http://www.ideal-country-property.com/flash/icpmenu_es/ICPmenu_es.htm)

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a good program to create a vertical drop-down Flash menu then please let me know. Thanks so much. Chris.

Comment: I'm confused. Flex publishes a swf, I'm not sure what you mean by 'However, if I publish it as an SWF I end up with the same problem. It won't play on its own, without the dependent files.' Are you hoping to embed all your graphics, xml, etc in the swf, and not have to put them on the server?

Comment: Hi Quoo, Yes that is EXACTLY what I'm after as I already have the SWF with all the dependent files created by the Flash menu program. I just want to be able to put the single SWF file on the server as you mentioned as I can't get it to play otherwise. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself properly.